# How to reference a specific value from another dataset different than first value(ssrs)?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

It's been quite some time and I can't still find an answer to my question, that's why I decided to take the time to ask the question since I was not able to find a good answer online.

Here is my situation, I have a reporting services table where I hide or show columns dinamically based on certain parameters, I was able to do that perfectly, 
Now  what I need is change the background color based on some other conditions.

All the information about the background color(including hex number color) is in my database like this:

[image: Each column will have a different value]

Let's say I have a column named "Test", I'd like to get the color where column name is Test. Example:
[image: I want the yellow value which is going to be the background color]

I tried with the Lookup function but it didn't work, i tried it this way:

lookup(Fields!columnName.Value,"Test",Fields!normalBgColor.Value,"Colors")

Note: "Colors" is another dataset, which ssrs seems to not recognize.

Comment: SO what is happening? Is there any error or any warnings ?

Comment: I think you need to change the order of the arguments: `=lookup("Test",Fields!columnName.Value,Fields!normalBgColor.Value,"Colors")` Just a guess as it's hard to try and replicate based on the information above, but I think it might help.

Comment: Did the suggestion help at all?

Comment: It didn't, but I was able to do it changing the procedure to return only one row and using First instead of lookup.